# how to rerun setTimeOut()?

Tags: javascript

How do you rerun (start from 0) a setTimeOut()?

This is what I am trying based on other questions: (it doesn't work)

```
var timer;
function talk() { 
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('#dialog').show();
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#dialog').hide();
        }, 2000);
}

$("#dialog").hover(function () {
    talk();
    });

talk();
```

How can I properly cancel anything on the settimeout and run it again?

You can see how it doesn't work here: [jsfiddle.net/yrBGm](http://jsfiddle.net/yrBGm)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161489/how-to-rerun-settimeout

Comment: @Keith.Abramo: But that's *this* question! So, not a "possible duplicate", but rather a "certain singlicate". :-)

Comment: Which part doesn't work? There is no concept of "rerunning" or starting from 0 with a timeout already queued - all you can do is cancel it and then create a new (unrelated) timeout. Having queued a timeout with `timer=setTimeout(...)` you can cancel it before it runs by calling `clearTimeout(timer)`. Your code already seems to be doing that.

Comment: Btw You can just write `$( '#dialog' ).show().delay( 2000 ).hide( 0 );`. That will work too since passing values into `show()` or `hide()` causes them to be added to the effects queue (instead of executed immediately).

Comment: I believe he is trying to EXTEND a timeout already scheduled.

Comment: You can't _extend_, only cancel and schedule again, but that's what the code already seems to be doing...

Comment: Sorry I should have explained how it didn't work. The problem is that it flashes. It still hides() the div and it flashes in and out. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrBGm/ I used fadeout instead of hide so the problem is more clear

Comment: It's simply not canceling the timer. When it should, I don't have the slightest clue why it doesn't cancel the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks if the hovering is happening. If so, it cancels the timeout and re-runs it later. If not, the timeout continues:

```
var timer;
function talk() { 
    if ($('#dialog2').hasClass('talking')) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#dialog2').removeClass('talking');
    } else  {
        $('#dialog').show();
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').hide();
        }, 2000);
    }
}

$("#dialog2").hover(function () {
    talk();
    $('#dialog2').addClass('talking');
});
```

EDIT:

Also, when you defined timer in "var timer;", timer is undefined, so you can test if it is undefined before you run it in the "timer = setTimeout(funcion () { ... like this:

```
if (timer == undefined) time = setTimeout( funciton () {
    ....
},time);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but this line will stop your pending timer:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

And, then if you want to start it again, you would do this:

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#dialog').hide();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Slight clarification on wording: `clearTimeout()` won't stop "any pending timer", just the one specified by the parameter. (Which for the code shown should be just the latest timer.)